# Building OpenCV for iOS results in larger framework than can be downloaded from website

Tags: ios, opencv, build

I am using OpenCV 3.3.0 in an app, but the prebuilt framework is rather large (>150MB). Since I'm only using functionality from one module, I thought I'd compile a custom framework, with just core, and the one other module I want.

I successfully built a framework using the included `build_framework.py` script. The only parameters I specify, other than the output directory, are about 30 `--without foo` parameters, corresponding to all modules that I don't want. But, the built framework is now 250MB!

How can a framework minus 30 modules be 100MB larger than the original framework? Unfortunately, I don't know what settings were used to make the prebuilt framework. I checked that all the defaults do a release (not debug) build. I also checked the headers subdirectory, and it only includes the header files for the modules I want, and the opencv_modules.hpp file only #defines the modules I want, so the `--without module` stuff is definitely working. I also used the `file` command to see which platforms the prebuilt and my libs target, and confirmed that they both target the same 5 platforms.

For comparison, I also did a default build, without removing any modules, and that was 450MB!

So, I'm wondering, how can I build a framework that is certainly no more than 150MB, like the prebuilt one - but ideally significantly smaller?

Comment: If you are using OpenCV for rectangle detecting, the CIDetector class can do the same thing. CIDetector is belong to the system, cost no extra space.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Alas, doesn't apply here.